# Unable to startx on Server

Tags: server, xorg, 17.04

I'm installing Ubuntu Server 17.4 on a PowerEdge R510, but i have some trouble running Xfce4: It seems that drivers for the Matrox G200 inside the server are missing.

I tried adding them by using `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-mga` without effects.

I tried to follow this guide too (https://wiki.ubuntu-it.org/Hardware/Video/Matrox/MgaClosed)

When I start a session remotely through SSH I can use X normally, but when i run `startx` locally, it fails with this error:

```
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.tional information. 
(EE) xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: connection refused
xinit: server error
```

Xorg.0.Log inside has this:

```
[  2224.049] 
X.Org X Server 1.19.3
Release Date: 2017-03-15
[  2224.066] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[  2224.083] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-70-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[  2224.121] Current Operating System: Linux PS1 4.10.0-24-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 14 08:14:34 UTC 2017 x86_64
[  2224.121] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.10.0-24-generic root=UUID=0e8c68ad-83c3-4e2e-9d73-48967c9956a3 ro
[  2224.187] Build Date: 28 March 2017  06:16:52AM
[  2224.235] xorg-server 2:1.19.3-1ubuntu1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[  2224.260] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[  2224.308]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[  2224.308] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  2224.437] (==) Log file: "/home/marce/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Jun 24 15:59:42 2017
[  2224.487] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  2224.610] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[  2224.610] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[  2224.610] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[  2224.610] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[  2224.611] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[  2224.611] (==) Automatically adding devices
[  2224.611] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[  2224.611] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[  2224.611] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[  2224.611] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[  2224.611] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[  2224.611]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2224.611] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[  2224.611]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2224.611] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[  2224.611]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2224.611] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[  2224.611]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2224.611] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[  2224.611]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2224.611] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[  2224.611] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  2224.611] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[  2224.611] (II) Loader magic: 0x55e129d87020
[  2224.611] (II) Module ABI versions:
[  2224.611]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[  2224.611]    X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
[  2224.611]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[  2224.611]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[  2224.612] (++) using VT number 1

[  2224.615] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_38
[  2224.619] (--) PCI:*(0:7:3:0) 102b:0532:1028:02f1 rev 10, Mem @ 0xd9800000/8388608, 0xde7fc000/16384, 0xde800000/8388608, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[  2224.619] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  2224.649] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  2224.655] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2224.655]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.0.0
[  2224.655]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[  2224.655] (==) Matched mga as autoconfigured driver 0
[  2224.655] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1
[  2224.655] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[  2224.655] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[  2224.655] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[  2224.655] (II) LoadModule: "mga"
[  2224.656] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module mga
[  2224.656] (II) UnloadModule: "mga"
[  2224.656] (II) Unloading mga
[  2224.656] (EE) Failed to load module "mga" (module does not exist, 0)
[  2224.656] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[  2224.656] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[  2224.662] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2224.662]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.19.3
[  2224.662]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  2224.662]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  2224.662] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[  2224.662] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[  2224.671] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2224.671]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 0.4.4
[  2224.671]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  2224.671]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  2224.671] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[  2224.671] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[  2224.684] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2224.684]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 2.3.4
[  2224.684]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  2224.684]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  2224.684] (==) Matched mga as autoconfigured driver 0
[  2224.684] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1
[  2224.684] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[  2224.684] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[  2224.684] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[  2224.684] (II) LoadModule: "mga"
[  2224.684] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module mga
[  2224.684] (II) UnloadModule: "mga"
[  2224.684] (II) Unloading mga
[  2224.684] (EE) Failed to load module "mga" (module does not exist, 0)
[  2224.684] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[  2224.684] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[  2224.684] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2224.684]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.19.3
[  2224.684]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  2224.684]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  2224.684] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[  2224.684] (II) Unloading modesetting
[  2224.684] (II) Failed to load module "modesetting" (already loaded, 0)
[  2224.684] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[  2224.684] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[  2224.684] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2224.684]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 0.4.4
[  2224.684]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  2224.684]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  2224.684] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[  2224.684] (II) Unloading fbdev
[  2224.684] (II) Failed to load module "fbdev" (already loaded, 0)
[  2224.684] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[  2224.684] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[  2224.684] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2224.684]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 2.3.4
[  2224.684]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  2224.684]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  2224.684] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[  2224.684] (II) Unloading vesa
[  2224.685] (II) Failed to load module "vesa" (already loaded, 0)
[  2224.685] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[  2224.685] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[  2224.685] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[  2224.685] xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
[  2224.685] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[  2224.685] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[  2224.685] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[  2224.685] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[  2224.685] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[  2224.685] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[  2224.712] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2224.713]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 0.0.2
[  2224.713]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  2224.713] (EE) open /dev/fb0: Permission denied
[  2224.713] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[  2224.713] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[  2224.713] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[  2224.713] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[  2224.713] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2224.713]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 0.0.2
[  2224.713]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  2224.713] (EE) open /dev/fb0: Permission denied
[  2224.713] (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
[  2224.713] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[  2224.713] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[  2224.713] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[  2224.713] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[  2224.713] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[  2224.713] (II) Loading sub module "vbe"
[  2224.713] (II) LoadModule: "vbe"
[  2224.713] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libvbe.so
[  2224.736] (II) Module vbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2224.736]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.1.0
[  2224.736]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  2224.736] (II) Loading sub module "int10"
[  2224.736] (II) LoadModule: "int10"
[  2224.736] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libint10.so
[  2224.745] (II) Module int10: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2224.745]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.0.0
[  2224.745]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  2224.745] (II) VESA(0): initializing int10
[  2224.745] (EE) VESA(0): Cannot read int vect
[  2224.746] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[  2224.746] (II) UnloadSubModule: "int10"
[  2224.746] (II) Unloading int10
[  2224.746] (II) UnloadSubModule: "vbe"
[  2224.746] (II) Unloading vbe
[  2224.746] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[  2224.746] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[  2224.746] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[  2224.746] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[  2224.746] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/marce/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[  2224.746] (EE) 
[  2224.794] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

When I tried using:
`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-mga`

```
            ========================================
               Matrox Linux Driver Install Script
            ========================================

            ERROR: X path could not be found. Please make
                   sure that an X server is installed.

            Please enter the full path to your current X directory above the modules directory:
            Examples: /usr/lib64/xorg or /usr/X11R6/lib64
```

I Wrote: `/usr/lib/xorg/`

```
            ./install.sh: line 138: test: Revision: binary operator expected
            ./install.sh: line 147: test: ./xserver/Revision: binary operator expected
            ./install.sh: line 171: [: ./xserver/Revision: binary operator expected
            Can't find the X Server version you are currently running (Revision 0) in
            this installers database, so for your convenience, I'll try to install
            the latest available version (7.1.0) onto your system.

            If you think this is alright, simply hit <RETURN> here, if you don't,
            stop here by pressing CTRL-C and please post this notice in the
            Unofficial Matrox Technical Support Forum (http://matrox.tuxx-home.at)
            and I'll see what I can do for you.

            Please strike any key to continue...
            You are about to install the X server driver,
            do you wish to continue? (y/n) y

            Installing X driver...

            Installing HAL driver...
```

All this without success.
What can I try more?

Comment: Did you install the X server? (Which is not installed by default on Ubuntu Server, the idea being that you don't need one) `sudo apt install xserver-common`

Comment: Yes it's installed, I just checked, I think that it is a dependency of xfce4 (to install it i did `sudo apt-get install xfce4`)